# zoom image on mouse scroll in angular4?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a piece of code which will zoomin/out on mouse scroll as shown below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src='https://www.cssscript.com/demo/image-zoom-pan-mouse-interactions-zoomnpan/zoomnpan.js'></script>
<style>
#demo {
  width: 460px;
  height: 250px;
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/3000/2000/?random);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
</style>

<div id="demo">
</div>

<script>
var p;
function enable(){
  p = new ZoomNPan(demo);
  p.minScale = 100;

}
enable();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I searching for the same functionality in angular. I have dynamically generated images where i want to zoom in/out on mouse scroll.

is there any library which works similarly as the code above?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

This will be an example and hope it will give you some information in the right direction.

What you can do is catch the events of mouse leave and enter within the html:

```
(mouseleave)=mouseLeave(yourLinkedID)
(mouseenter)=mouseEnter(yourLinkedID)
```

Now you know if your mouse is inside the picture ore not.
Next you want to catch the scroll event.

`(scroll)="onScroll($event)"`

Now the last trick is to us ngStyle like:

`[ngStyle]="{'background-size': backgroundSize}"`

In your component the enter will set a value to true and the leave to false:

```
onScroll(_ev: any) {
  if(this.entered){
    //do something with event
    //if scroll up this.backgroundSize 50% +5
    //if scroll down this.backgroundSize 50% -5
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If that script works for you, you can use it instead of looking for some other angular ready framework.

to use it :

- download the script you want, put it in your asset folder or basically where you want it to stay
- go to your `angular-cli.json` or sometimes `angular.json`. and add the script you just download in your scripts array like this :

  ```
  "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",

        "../src/assets/js/core/jquery.perfect-scrollbar.min.js"
    ],
  ```

  here I am adding `Jquery` and a `Jquery plugin`.
- in your angular `.ts` component file add :

  `declare var ZoomNPan:any;`
  on top of your `@component` Tag.
- use your `ZoomNPan` as if you are doing in vanilla javascript ( just like in your demo )

**Note :** You can use this method to add all kind of scripts.